# Unable to view Pentaho EE BI server user console on OSX

Tags: tomcat, osx-mavericks, pentaho

I'm attempting to start the Pentaho EE BI Server user console on OSX without success. I did a default install using the installation wizard and attempting to start the server with the `ctlscript.sh` script. The script output doesn't show any errors:

`waiting for server to start.... done
server started
/Applications/Pentaho/postgresql/scripts/ctl.sh : postgresql  started at port 5432
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Applications/Pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Applications/Pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Applications/Pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Applications/Pentaho/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /Applications/Pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
/Applications/Pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh : BA Server started
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Applications/Pentaho/server/data-integration-server/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Applications/Pentaho/server/data-integration-server/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Applications/Pentaho/server/data-integration-server/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Applications/Pentaho/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /Applications/Pentaho/server/data-integration-server/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
/Applications/Pentaho/server/data-integration-server/scripts/ctl.sh : data-integration-server started`

But going to the site at `http://localhost:8080/pentaho/` shows a generic Tomcat 404 page.

Reviewing the logs shows a slew of java errors with stack traces but I'm not certain which one could cause the problem.

Here is the output for the pentaho.log: http://pastebin.com/ZxJJfZfr

Here is the output for the catalina.log: http://pastebin.com/nyfSwrG1

Does anyone have a clue as to what could be causing it?

Comment: Did you make any changes to configuration files, or is that a plain vanilla install? In particular, did you make changes to /Applications/Pentaho/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/system/pentahoObjects.spring.xml ? Does stopping and restarting the server help in any way? Also, do you have a web.xml file inside /Applications/Pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/ ?

Comment: @nsousa: It's a plain vanilla install using the "default" option. No edits made to pentahoObjects.spring.xml. Stop/Start/Restart doesn't seem to make a difference. Yes, I do have a web.xml file in that folder.

Comment: That's odd. There's no reason for it not to start. I have a Mac myself and it ran out of the box. What intrigues me is the chain of errors on your catalina.log, which start at "SEVERE: Exception starting filter Spring Security Filter Chain Proxy
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChainProxy' defined in file [/Applications/Pentaho/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml". Sorry, I can't help you any further via stachexchange comments. Try support@pentaho.com, they should be able to help.